# Diagonal Scrolling rationale

Tags: tables, scrolling, touch-screen, mobile-web

I m trying to find rationale for implementation of horizontal scrolling on a mobile web browser for a table. The following are the one's I could think of, if you have any other rationale in mind or disagree with the one's I have right now. Please feel free to add.

1. Since mobile devices have less real estate than desktop the UI element needs to be fluid.
2. Fluidity helps the user to focus in a more efficient way on a specific cell of a table in case the user wants to get a cell which is on far right to the middle of the screen without doing movements for two coordinates ( horizontal and vertical).

Thanks

Comment: Please be more concrete or ask an actual question.

Comment: Thanks for closing the question. My original question was for diagonal scrolling but I didn't realize (dnbrv) edited the question and took into a more abstract level by changing diagonal to horizontal. Maybe there should be a way in this forum where people don't edit questions without permission, rather than closing questions in such a manner.

Comment: Hi varun, the edit history for your question doesn't show anyone changing the content of your question. All @dnbrv did was change some tags. The reason it was closed is because you haven't actually asked a question, you've just showed us a list and offered to have us add to it. If you're looking for help building your list, why not visit the chat?

Comment: The chat needs something named "20 reputation". Anyways it's fine, I realize the problem. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Accepting anwers is a good way to bring your reputation up.

Comment: Okay, seems like I have the reputation points needed. The message on the top gave me a impression that for some reason I need some extra points to get access to chat room. Wish that message on top disappeared after some time. The page I m referring to is the chat page. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add:

- mobile (touchscreen) devices allow an easier horizontal scrolling (horizontal scrolling was a taboo for the web because the limits of the mouse).

Just be sure to allow your users to always see the header/row number of the table so they can see where they are.

You could also allow for a zoom in/out function to let them navigate the table